# Как извлечь данные из кнопки Яндекс.Денег

Tags: javascript, yandex-money

У меня на сайте есть кнопка такого вида:

[image: Яндекс.Деньги]

Вот её код:

```
<a href="https://money.yandex.ru/embed/?from=sbal" title="Виджеты Яндекс.Денег" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; display: block; margin-bottom: 0.6em; background: url('https://money.yandex.ru/share-balance.xml?id=45454545454&key=4545454545454') 0 0 no-repeat; -background: none; -filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='https://money.yandex.ru/share-balance.xml?id=4545454545&key=4545454545454', sizingMethod = 'crop');"></a>
```

Мне нужно иметь возможность оперировать с вот этой цифрой внутри кнопки (в данном случае - 98), а конкретно - чтобы я мог работать с ней в javascript'e. То есть сохранить её в переменную с возможностью автоматического обновления её значения при изменении суммы, указанной в кнопке.

Comment: Вам сюда - https://tech.yandex.ru/money/doc/dg/concepts/About-docpage/

Answer (score 0):

Никак.

В качестве бэкграунда блока выводится картинка, сформированная на сайте Яндекс.